# Combining values and annotate on a django query

Tags: python, sql, django

I have a query that looks like the following:

```
filter = Q(filter stuff)
q = MyModel.objects.filter(filter).order_by().values('c1', 
                                                     'c2', 
                                                     'c3').annotate(Sum('c2'), Sum('c3'))
```

Now when I do this, the output essentially has all the unique triples of `c1`, `c2`, and `c3`.  Which I don't want.  I want it find all the unique values of `c1`, and add up the corresponding values of `c2` and `c3`.

I was able to fix this by changing the query to the following

```
q = MyModel.objects.filter(filter).order_by().values('c1', 
                                                    ).annotate(Sum('c2'), Sum('c3'))
```

Which is great and gives me the desired output...but what I don't understand is why...

Shouldn't `values` specify the columns that I want, not restrict the output to the unique pairings of those outputs?  Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Now when I do this, the output essentially has all the unique triples of `c1`, `c2`, and `c3`.

`values()` is going to return an object's specific set of `c1`, `c2` and `c3` as a dictionary. Yes, this is expected behavior.

Moving on:

> I want it find all the unique values of c1, and add up the corresponding values of c2 and c3.

Alrighty than: first get the `c1` value for each object in the queryset with value and then use annotate to add the sums of 'c2' and 'c3'. 
You thit a good job doing that.

So yes, this is correct:

```
q = MyModel.objects.filter(filter).order_by().values('c1', 
                                                    ).annotate(Sum('c2'), Sum('c3'))
```

> Shouldn't values specify the columns that I want, not restrict the
>   output to the unique pairings of those outputs?

In this case the column you want is `c1`, you don't really want the columns `c2` and `c3`, you just want to aggregate sum them.

`values()` is going to restrict the output to the unique pairings because that is a row in the database. There is no magic in `values()`, it just turns a model instance into a dictionary.

Hope it helps.